# Why do these statements work differently in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, xor

I was recently checking out sweet little code to swap two variables using `XOR` function. I used JavaScript for this.

Let x and y be two variables and let `x = 4, y = 6`.

`x = x ^ y;
 y = y ^ x;
 x = x ^ y;`

It swaps variables nicely. Notice that I'm keeping `x` and `y` different to prevent aliasing which can occur due to first `XOR`.

Then, observing the statement, I wrote:
`x = x ^ (y = y ^ (x = x ^ y ));`
This swaps variable `y` correctly but makes `x` always `0`.

Also, `x ^= y ^= x ^= y;` which also seems to be equivalent expression yields the same incorrect result as in second case.

However, all these statements run equivalently on Java and produce the same result consistently.

I also used strict mode with JavaScript.

Are these three statements somehow not equivalent on JavaScript or am I missing something critical here?

Comment: try `x = (y = y ^ (x = x ^ y )) ^ x;` instead - you had x needing changed before assessing... The last other won't work because the first part of `x^` (finding the start value) is done before x is re-assigned.

Comment: a type-independent swap w/o temp lexical: `var x= 4, y= 6; x=[y, y= x][0]; [x,y]`

Comment: @dandavis Your solution works like a charm. Thanks. I found my error. Stupid me. Thanks once again.

Comment: @dandavis an ES6 swap is just simply `let x = 4, y = 6; [x, y] = [y, x];`

Comment: @dandavis This works fine `x=(y^=(x^=y))^x;`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Thanks for the latest standard. Seems cleaner.

Comment: @Ozil but in both the dandavis's and my type-agnostic swaps, it does have the overhead of creating a temporary array, so neither of them are technically without a temporary lexical.

Comment: @Ozil In practice, it is better to swap two values by using a temporary variable. The JIT compiler will recognise what you are doing and write appropriate optimised code. Also, anyone maintaining your code (which includes you in a few months) will have an easier time seeing the intention.

Comment: @Andrew Morton Absolutely. I was just looking for fun new ways to implement swap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
x = x ^ y;
y = y ^ x;
x = x ^ y;
```

This works because it's like

```
x_1 = x_0 ^ y_0;
y_1 = y_0 ^ x_1;
x_2 = x_1 ^ y_1;
```

Then,

```
x_final = x_2 = x_1 ^ y_1 = x_0 ^ y_0 ^ y_0 ^ x_1 = x_0 ^ y_0 ^ y_0 ^ x_0 ^ y_0
        = y_0
y_final = y_1 = y_0 ^ x_1 = y_0 ^ x_0 ^ y_0
        = x_0;
```

Your `x = x ^ (y = y ^ (x = x ^ y ));` is like

```
x_1 = x_0 ^ y_0;
y_1 = y_0 ^ x_1;
x_2 = x_0 ^ y_1;
```

Then,

```
x_final = x_2 = x_0 ^ y_1 = x_0 ^ y_0 ^ x_1 = x_0 ^ y_0 ^ x_0 ^ y_0
        = 0
y_final = y_1 = y_0 ^ x_1 = y_0 ^ x_0 ^ y_0
        = x_0;
```

It would have worked if you used `x = (y = y ^ (x = x ^ y )) ^ x;`.

That's because JS parses the expressions from left to right, and you want that `x` to be the modified value, not the initial one.

Comment: x ^ (y = y ^ (x = x ^ y)); is not the same as (y = y ^ (x = x ^ y)) ^ x; is all you want to say, right?

Comment: @user1589188 In short, yes